# Freeze Data Tables plugin header using css

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am Using datatables jQuery Plugin http://www.datatables.net/ to display data row wise.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-AYO8f7kUw1c/UUlW8jzpisI/AAAAAAAAAC4/0fvbh1gFoko/w854-h262-p-o-k/datatable.png

I want to Freeze the header of this table without using the plugin features and using CSS

I tried using Position: Fixed.
but it not working as per the requirements

Comment: what do you mean by "Freeze"? Can you provide an example using Fiddle?

Comment: mean when we have a long list of data in table and when we scroll the page the table header should not move along the page scroll, on the table data (Td) should scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want: [table header fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Dyzxe/)

I have used position: fixed; to achieve this.

```
thead {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#c2c2c2;
    text-align:center; 
    position:fixed; top:0px;
}
```